# Matlab Camera Calibration: saving chessboard calibration images

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I'm currently trying to calibrate a camera and use those data to calibrate a projector. The first [steps](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/own_calib.html) of this process start with printing a chessboard, generate chessboard calibration images and use them to calibrate the camera. Matlab documentation is quite thorough but it doesn't mention how one can generate its own chessboard calibration images. I can only assume this is a fairly simple thing to do but I'm new to Matlab so haven't figured out yet so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate the calibration images by taking pictures of the chessboard with your camera.

Also, if you have a recent version of MATLAB with the Computer Vision System Toolbox, try the [Camera Calibrator app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/find-camera-parameters-with-the-camera-calibrator.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://sites.google.com/site/visheshpanjabihomepage/codes

The second set of codes, will help you collect the images for the camera calibration toolbox by Dr. Boquet (Link of which is given on the prescribed page itself).